# Want to trigger an adding score adding effect in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a trigger an adding score effect when user's score changing.

Here is the code I currently have:

```js
let speed = 200;
let div = document.querySelector('div')
let olddiv = parseFloat(div.textContent)
let interval;
function change(increase){
   let add = increase/speed

   interval = setInterval(function(){
    div.textContent = parseFloat(div.textContent) +add;
    if(div.textContent > olddiv + increase){
        div.textContent = olddiv+ increase
        window.clearInterval(interval)
    }
   },1)
}
change(5000)
```

```html
<div>1000</div>
```

The code works fine but I add 25 (increase/speed value)  per milliseconds.

I want to make the score adding 1 every times. I tried to use `for` loop, but `for` loop will not shows the adding effect.

Also, since the `setInterval` doesn't accept milliseconds lower than 1, I can't use this code as well (this code will execute 1 ms every time which is too slow.

```js
   let speed = 200;
    let div = document.querySelector('div')
    let olddiv = parseFloat(div.textContent)
    let interval;
    function change(increase){
       let addspeed = speed/increase;
       interval = setInterval(function(){
        div.textContent = parseFloat(div.textContent) +1;
        if(div.textContent > olddiv + increase){
            div.textContent = olddiv+ increase
            window.clearInterval(interval)
        }
       },addspeed)
    }
    change(5000)
```

```html
<div>1000</div>
```

Could anyone give me any solution of solving this problem?

Thanks for any responds!

Comment: Well... This is the fastest your machine can do... no interval less than 1. why do you need the code to add 1 only? If you ask your users - they won't tell the difference between 1 or 10 or 25. It's not that interesting for the user

Comment: @Eldshe, I agree. But just curious if there is any way to do that:)